# Vehicle cut out whilst driving

Tags: engine, oil-leak, power

Was driving a Holden Vectra 2002 2.2 Litre, when the engine randomly cut out, went to turn back on was having difficulties turning over, on top of that after turning back on and driving the accelerator stopped working and the steering locked just before cutting out again after driving another 150m.

Literally bought a new battery today and got it fitted by a professional, but when I checked the dipstick oil was empty, although got an oil change and filled with oil a week prior to this. Also has a leak in the exhaust manifold if this helps.

What could be the problem? And how much to fix?

Comment: You should take it up with the shop that did the oil change. If it was done a week ago, that is suspiciously close in time.

Have you checked to see if your drain plug is still intact?

Answer (score 2):

If you ran the engine without oil, it may have seized, or partially seized, the engine. This would explain why turning over was difficult immediately after the event. If this is the case, there is likely some internal engine damage.

Regardless of when or who changed the oil, you should always check it to verify it is at the proper level. Technically, we should do this before we start the car each time, but most people do not. If the engine leaks or burns oil, it is even more critical to check and maintain the oil level.

*"How much to fix?"* This site does not give pricing/shopping advice. You will have to talk to your professional and see if there is any real damage done and what it will cost to repair.